# How to show a subgraph in Neo4j browser?

Tags: neo4j

I'm trying to learn Neo4j and am currently playing around with the movie graph, by opening a neo4j browser, entering
`:play movie graph`
and following the instructions. The instructions provide like this:

```
<500 lines of CREATE statements>

WITH TomH as a
MATCH (a)-[:ACTED_IN]->(m)<-[:DIRECTED]-(d) RETURN a,m,d LIMIT 10;
```

which creates the movie graph database, and displays a small subgraph consisting of 10 movies that Tom Hanks acted in, and their directors. However, when I try to just return this subgraph, i.e. without creating the graph again by simply running the last two lines, I get

```
Variable `TomH` not defined (line 1, column 6 (offset: 5))
"WITH TomH as a"
```

Can anybody explain why this is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The script that generates the Movies graph does a whole bunch of stuff as one big statement and so has already got a notion of who Tom Hanks is and has assigned him to a variable called `TomH`. However, outside of that statement none of those variables exist - once it's run, `TomH` is meaningless (which is why you're being told it's not defined).

You can see what all node labels, relationships and properties are defined for the graph directly in the browser - clicking on any of them will return a sample of some of the data for that node/relationship:

[image]

To recreate the 'world of Tom Hanks' graph:

```
MATCH (a: Person { name: 'Tom Hanks' })-[:ACTED_IN]->(m)<-[:DIRECTED]-(d) RETURN a,m,d LIMIT 10
```

Comment: Thanks, can I ask how you know whether to specify that you're looking for a person?
I'm confused that `MATCH (tom {name: "Tom Hanks"}) RETURN tom` works but `MATCH (a {name: {"Tom Hanks"}})-[:ACTED_IN]->(m)<-[:DIRECTED]-(d) RETURN a,m,d LIMIT 10;` fails.

Comment: I've added a little more around how to tell what all data is in the graph. Ultimately you can either 'browse' the graph (use the sidebar and see what node labels exist, select some and expand some interactively to get a feel for the structure) or you could look at the Movies script that was run which shows that Tom Hanks is modelled as a 'Person'-type node.

Comment: Thanks, I understand he is a Person type node, but I don't understand why I don't have to specify that when I just query the node, but I do have to when querying the subgraph.

Comment: Ah - because in your second example you've got two sets of curly braces (you've surrounded the string 'Tom Hanks' with curly braces accidentally). The following works: `MATCH (a { name: 'Tom Hanks' })-[:ACTED_IN]->(m)<-[:DIRECTED]-(d) RETURN a,m,d LIMIT 10`

Comment: Gah, thanks so much. If I can ask one last stupid question: I tried running the same statement without the LIMIT.
For somw reason this shows me 3 copies of the subgraph. Any idea why this is?

`MATCH (a {name: "Tom Hanks"})-[:ACTED_IN]->(m)<-[:DIRECTED]-(d) RETURN a,m,d;`

Comment: No, not sure - I'd raise another question with a screenshot and full repro steps I think